# How to select an item in UiPath that starts with a string

Tags: uipath

I'm using UiPath to select an item from a combobox in a windows rich client application.  The items are formatted in the list as "Code - Description".  I'd like to select the item by code only, rather than needing to know the description also.

As a UIPath newbie, thoughts on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a wildcard in selector. Given that Code is unique i.e 0001 and attribute name equals to id:

```
<id = 0001* />
```

Additionally, this link should be helpfull:

https://studio.uipath.com/v2017.1/docs/selectors-with-wildcards